# Dropbox API login no longer works on iOS 10 after upgrade to Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dropbox-api

I have used Dropbox API (Objective C) in my app with Swift using pods. It was working perfectly till Xcode 8 beta 5. After installing beta 6, I am not able to login using Dropbox. App is crashed when I am trying to login. Anyone can please help me?

```
flow:start_secondary_connect

nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect

nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Transport protocol connected

nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport

nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected

nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]

nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied

nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[6.1 108.160.172.238:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6.1 108.160.172.238:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect

nw_connection_endpoint_report [6 www.dropbox.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect

__tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 6 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE in response to state ready and error (null)

tcp_connection_event_notify 6 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE, reason: nw_connection event, should deliver: true

tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 7ms/12ms since start, TCP: 20ms/46ms since start, TLS: 1880ms/1921ms since start
```

Comment: Can you add the name and version of the library you're using, if any, as well as the relevant code?

Comment: (You said the magic word: "crash".)  What does a symbolicated stack trace look like when you crash?

Comment: I have used **pod 'Dropbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.3.13'** for integrating Dropbox Api in my app and this is the link which I have referred. [Dropbox Api integration](https://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/) @Greg

Comment: Can you share the relevant code though? Also, to reiterate Phillip, is this the only output you get? It doesn't look like a stack trace.